How to extend an open source lib that have no extension points?
I want to be able to extend maven RequireUpperBounds rule.
Running the rule from maven enforcer will output the result as a string but I want to use it as a java object (as it is in the source code)
My bad choices are :
A. Write my own rule that parse the result from string. (ignore the source code)
B. Use maven source code as Fork and customize it to my needs. Lose future enhancements to the code.
C. Inherit from the rule and customize. But the original rule does not expose the result (execute method is void) and in the c'tor I need to pass in a dependent type that is internal. So it seems impossible. Correct me if I'm wrong here...
Assuming my code is too specific to be merged to maven repo, is there any way I can extend the original code/functionality?
And maintain the ability to receive updates

Maven Enforcer supports custom rules: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html. Why do you think it has "no extension points"?

@Michael I think the OP is talking about extending a specific enforcer rule. You could e.g. inherit from a given rule and write your own, more specific or extended rule.

@JFabianMeier Yes. I wanted to extend that rule but need to initialize it with org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.ResolverUtil in the constructor which is non public. any way around it?
